# Why can't I find a controllers folder in visual studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, controllers

Why can't I find the controllers folder for visual studio 2017 for Mac? I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app-mac/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-2.1 
And on the part of the controllers folder, I don't have it on my solutions explorer. I have see a post similar to this about not finding the controllers folder but that the solution didn't work for me. I'm not sure if I could make the controllers folder show up. Here's how my solution explorer looks like.[my solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFDpI.png) I need to just find the controllers folder to show like this: [screenshot with a controllers folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMVhL.png). Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess you can just add a folder to your solution called controller and then follow these instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app-mac/adding-controller?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: What type of project did you create? For instance a plain "class library project" would not need "controllers", but an "ASP.Net MVC project" would.

Comment: Judging from his screenshot (my solution explorer) it's an MVC application.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that you created a [Razor Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) Project instead of an MVC project. That's why you don't see the controller folder.

I don't know about Visual Studio for Mac, but in visual studio for Windows when I create a new .NET Core Web App, I am then promted to chose between Web application (ie Razor Page), Web Application MVC, empty and more

The easiest solution is to start over and create and create a new MVC project.

But can keep your existing project if you want and can add a Controllers, a Views folder, a Models folder. Add the _Layout and ViewStart views and add the controllers and views that you need.

I you do that you have to configure the routing of MVC by replacing in Startup.cs

```
app.UseMvc();
```

by

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: This should be accepted as answer. The OP project does not look like MVC project. Just restart is the easiest way.